# How to cancel _doPostBack

Tags: c#, sql, href, dopostback

i have a problem that i cannot solve. i just want to click one button then trigger C# code to write entered string to sql and open other aspx web site. however after writing string to sql, page is being refreshed codes are below

```
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <a href="A3_Maturity.aspx" id="StarttoEvaluate" runat="server" class="btn btn-primary"  onserverclick="StarttoEvaluate_Click" >Enter</a>
                </div>
```

C#

```
    protected void StarttoEvaluate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        
    protected void StarttoEvaluate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        
        SqlCommand comd = new SqlCommand("insert into A3_Coaching (name) values (@p1)", con.connection());
        comd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", A3name.Value.ToString());
        comd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.connection().Close();


    }
```

Comment: Any reason why you do not have a `using` on your command and connection objects? And why you don't supply the type and size of the string to `SqlParameter`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have the redirection in your server side code. After doing all the server side work you can add below line:

```
Response.Redirect("A3_Maturity.aspx");
```

Comment: it works well. thank you very much. i think is was easy question :D but i can say i'm newbie :)